# Postgres INSERT ON CONFLICT behavior with INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers, insert

Suppose I have the following tables and view:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a(
    field_x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    id SERIAL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE table_b(
    a_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES table_a(id),
    field_y INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON table_a.id=table_b.a_id;
```

I want to be able to insert into the view, so I created the following function and trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_into_view()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
   DECLARE new_id INTEGER;
   BEGIN
      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO table_a (field_x) VALUES (NEW.field_x) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id INTO new_id;
        IF new_id IS NULL THEN
          SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE field_x=NEW.field_x INTO new_id;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO table_b (a_id, field_y) VALUES (new_id, NEW.field_y);
      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
$function$;
CREATE TRIGGER view_insert_trigger
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON
      v FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_into_view();
```

Now I want to insert values into the view only if there does not exist a row for field_x yet in the view, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO v (field_x, field_y) VALUES (5,6);
INSERT INTO v (field_x, field_y) VALUES (5,8) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Where I want the second insert to silently do nothing. However, I get this:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_b_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (a_id)=(2) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO table_b (a_id, field_y) VALUES (new_id, NEW.field_y)"
```

I know why I'm getting this error: the function `insert_into_view` does not specify ON CONFLICT behavior when inserting into `table_b` and by default the query fails. Thus my question: can I make the ON CONFLICT behavior to ripple from the view insert into the table insert? (I may want to specify different conflict behavior at a later time, so I don't want to hard-code this in the trigger function if I can avoid it.)

Thanks!

Comment: you sure you did not mess up with field_x and field_y?.. I did not understand the question, so tried to get it from code, but it seems not clear as well - sorry

Comment: Edited my question with workable code, and what I expect. Hope it's clearer?

Comment: yes. I think you can't use `ON CONFILCT` on `INSTEAD RULE` - only on physical (not foreign, not view) table with unique constraint

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure If I understand you right. But I try:

if you change

```
INSERT INTO table_b (a_id, field_y) VALUES (new_id, NEW.field_y)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO table_b (a_id, field_y) VALUES (new_id, NEW.field_y) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

in function it will start working silently.

Regarding

```
INSERT INTO v (field_x, field_y) VALUES (5,8) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

I think you can use `ON CONFLICT` only on tables with unique constraint, so and foreign table, and instead rule will ignore `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` and fail when you specify target_name of constraint_name

Comment: I don't want to fix the conflict behavior in the trigger function, as that's too inflexible. I was hoping to somehow figure out in the trigger what the original query's conflict resolution strategy was.